# как заменить в элементах массива NULL на пустоту в выдаче mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

в php из mysql получаю массив в некоторых элементах содержится NULL в тоге ява скрипт вываливает null текстом на страницу

как заменить null  на 'нет'  в массиве?

Comment: ``COALESCE(`field`, 'нет') AS `field` ``

Comment: Круто, спасибо!